# Ionic File google-services.json is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using ionic and capacitor, when i try to build my app in android studio it says:

> File google-services.json is missing

While my file exist.

Existed `google-service.json` in `Android` and `Android/app` folders

[image: one]

Android Studio error

[image: two]

**Any idea?**

Comment: Searched locations are wrong. Take a closer look at error message. For some reason, Ionic or Android Studio searched under the directory `src/nullnull/`.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu what could cause that? till last night that i created debug file everything was fine.

Comment: Not sure exactly. Try adding `uaSkipApplyGoogleServicesPlugin=true` into `gradle.properties` if you use UrbanAirship.

Comment: to me problem was caused by `FCM` plugin and nothing could fix it, so I just had to remove it. :/

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any solution ?